# using non -primary key attribute (which is unique) as foreign key in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have two tables Sales and Opportunity.

Sales : salesId , oppNo , status

Opportunity: oppId, oppNo, status

And I have mapped oppNo which is not the primary key but unique as foreign key in Sales table

And Mapping in  Sales Table is :

```
@JoinColumn(name = "opportunity_no", referencedColumnName = "opportunity_no")
@ManyToOne
private TsOpportunities opportunityNo;
```

However, when I update the sales record with

```
sales.setOpportunityNumber(opportunityObject)
```

Hibernate does not copy the value of the opportunity number in the Opportunity table to the Sales table

How do I make it copy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out that this issue happened as I used `session.load(Opportunity, id);` to fetch the Opportunity Object. That way only the primary key was fetched. After using criteria to get the object it worked